# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to convert … 'AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.Widget.CoordinatorLayout' to type 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been trying for hours on running my Xamarin app in Visual Studio, but it only shows the splash screen and then stops!

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to convert instance of type 'AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.Widget.CoordinatorLayout' to type 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar'.'

Before that I actually deleted the design file and now tried to create a new one because of the newly defined toolbar (which I do not need it anymore). I tried most of the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012251/xamarinunable-to-convert-instance-of-type-android-widget-linearlayout-to-type-a) but I don't know why they didn't work with me.

This is **MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;

namespace FinalApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "FinalApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme",     ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
}
```

This is **toolbar.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

I expect the app to run normally but only splash screen is displayed and then the app breaks.

Comment: toolbar.xml, or toobar.axml?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70450181/19335715) to fix the error. As the error said that Since you are using the latest Xamarin Forms Activity which uses AndroidX, you need to convert your legacy libraries into AndroidX ones.